# Cannot read property 'value' of null Error in first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try get a value of my option/select for use it in states in future, but when I try get element by ID, i got error "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
import React from "react";

function Inputs() {
  const Period = document.getElementById("Period");

  console.log(Period);

  const inputHandler = (inputName) => {
    console.log(inputName.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Period:</label>
      <select id="Period" onChange={() => inputHandler(Period)}>
        <option>Last 12 month</option>
        <option>Last 6 month</option>
        <option>Last month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Inputs;
```

[Link to the SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-smoke-r9s4w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Try to do it in useEffect, because at initial the select tag not initialized

Comment: The reason why Period is null is because when the component is mounted, there is no DOM painted already so the selector is not able to find an non-exist element

Checkout this solution https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-snow-4ylgb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the solution bellow:

```
import React from "react";

function RechartsInputs() {
  const Period = document.getElementById("Period");

  console.log(Period);

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Period:</label>
      <select id="Period" onChange={e => inputHandler(e)}>
        <option>Last 12 month</option>
        <option>Last 9 month</option>
        <option>Last 6 month</option>
        <option>Last 3 month</option>
        <option>Last month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RechartsInputs;
```

hope it helps ;D

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. Follow with this.
Use `useEffect` and `useState`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function RechartsInputs() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(val);
  }, [val]);

  const inputHandler = (event) => {
    setVal(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Period:</label>
      <select id="Period" onChange={inputHandler}>
        <option>Last 12 month</option>
        <option>Last 9 month</option>
        <option>Last 6 month</option>
        <option>Last 3 month</option>
        <option>Last month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RechartsInputs;
```

Comment: Your solution are good and work, but I'm should not use States at this component, because i'm pass this values on neighboring component through the parent component

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use `document.getElementById` with React this way.

You need to understand that you are using [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) which is a templating engine that reads all the tags that your component is returning and compiles it to JavaScript in order to generate the HTML. So what you are doing is trying to query the element before it's rendered and thats why you get null.

You could use a [lifecycle callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) like `componentDidMount` or a [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) like `useEffect` in order to get notified when the HTML was rendered and then use `document.getElementById` but it's not recommended to access elements like this.

In order to get a reference to the element you can use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) even though it's better to create a handler for the `onChange` event and get the value from the event target.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the input before the render at that time it will be obviously `null`

Use the `event.target` to access the input

```
import React from "react";

function Inputs() {

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Period:</label>
      <select id="Period" onChange={(e) => inputHandler(e)}>
        <option>Last 12 month</option>
        <option>Last 6 month</option>
        <option>Last month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Inputs;
```

Comment: Thank you, but your try run your code ? It doesn't work

Comment: @Miltosh t h I don't have system to run react atm. Does any other code work?